# making one network with ISP modem & own router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, wireless-access-point

I have a modem from my ISP, with 2 LAN ports and a wireless network. (let's call these network A and wireless network A.)

I bought a TP-link TL-WR1043ND, that has 1 internet port, 4 lan ports, and is able to emit a wireless network. (let's call these network B and wireless network B.)

The ISP modem A has a default wireless network A configured, witch is fine, because I updated the security settings. There's also a device on network A, but those can communicate with each other.

When i add my router B (connect the internet port B to a lan network A port) to the network, it creates another network, with a different subnet, and devices from network A are in WAN. Devices from wireless network B can comunicate to network B, but not to network A or wireless network A.

Is there any way to set my router B to emit wireless network A, and to connect devices in lan ports to network A? I'm basicly trying to have one network emitted by 2 devices, but i can't connect lan A to lan B because i need the wireless settings.

Comment: You need to take the ISP modem Router and put that in Bridge mode. Basically turn everything off inside the router part. Usually when you call the ISP they can do this for you. Then all you have to do is use Wireless Network A "which is no longer wireless at this point" as a Modem and your Router Wireless Network B will now be the Primary. You will no longer have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **You must set your router as an Access Point, from its control panel.**
2. **Set the wireless on the TP-LINK router to broadcast the same SSID as the ISP modem, but on a different channel, to reduce interference.**

   - For 2.4Ghz, a hop of five channels is a good bet for no interference (ignoring other networks around): 1, 6, 11; 2, 7, (12 EU/JP); 3, 8, (13 EU/JP); 4, 9, (14 JP); 5, 10. Of course, you can choose a bigger gap between them: 1, 11; 2, 10; 3, 9.
     [image: 2.4Ghz]

   img source: [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783011%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

   - For 5Ghz, the common channels (36,40,44,48) are non-overlapping, just chose two different for the modem and router.
     [image: 5Ghz]

   img source: [Unex](http://www.unex.com.tw/802-11ac-gigabit-wi-fi)
3. **Connect it from a LAN port of the ISP modem to another LAN port of your TP-LINK router (NOT to the WAN port).**
4. **Final toughts:** you are actually transforming your normal router into a simple Ethernet switch with an Wireless Access Point attached to it.